# How do I Know webserver resources calls like image, css, js files etc included in a single HttpServlet Request in programmatically

Tags: java, webserver, application-server, servlet-listeners

My mission is showing the clients what files are being transmitted over the internet in a single Http request on my web application.

For this, I tried to use the RequestListner in Servlet API. But the API did not listen the static resource request at all.

How can I implement in java?

thanks in advance!

Comment: By coding, what have you tried?

Comment: When Users input some URL by browser, I intercepted this request with HttpRequestListener. But this way did not listen the static resource request like image file, css file etc on..